# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField.onChanged doesn't update UI

Tags: flutter

I have a screen with a `DropdownButtonFormField`:

```
var _list = ['foo', 'bar'];
String _value;

build() {
  ...
  DropdownButtonFormField(
    items: _items(ctx),
    onChanged: (item) => _onChanged(ctx, item),
    value: _value,
  )
  ...
}

List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _items(ctx) {
  final specialNone = DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text('NONE'),
    value: '#none',
  );
  final specialNew = DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text('CREATE NEW'),
    value: '#new',
  );

  return [
    specialNone,
    specialNew,
    ..._list.map((o) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(o), value: o)).toList()
  ];
}

void _onChanged(ctx, String value) async {
  if (value == '#new') {
    final result = await Navigator.pushNamed(ctx, '/vendor');

    if (result != null)
      setState(() {
        _list.add(result);
        _value = result;
      });
  } else if (value == '#none')
    setState(() {
      _value = null;
    });
  else
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
    });
}
```

There's a special item "CREATE NEW" in the items list. When clicked, a new item will be added to the list, and I want it to be selected instead of selecting "CREATE NEW".

NOTE: If you change `DropdownButtonFormField` to `DropdownButton`, it will work.

Comment: Since this is pseudo-code I'm not really able to tell what's going on with your code. Can you provide an entire example of real code instead?

Comment: @SupposedlySam question overhauled with real code

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the onChanged to be null so the value cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code if you doesn't want to update UI

```
DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged:(value){},
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Please try with `DropdownButtonFormField`, and you'll be surprised that your `onChanged` is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

#### What's going on?

Using a [DropdownButtonFormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField-class.html) vs a [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) wraps the `DropdownButton` with a [FormField](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html) that maintains the current state of the form field.

#### What does this mean?

When you call `setState` on your class, your widget rebuilds like it's supposed to, but the `FormField`s state is not updated so it doesn't look like anything happened. However, the list of items that's nested in the `DropdownButton` (inside the `DropdownButtonFormField`) is being updated appropriately.

#### Possible Solution

I would suggest trying to use the `selectedItemBuilder` method of the `DropdownButtonFormField` and see if that allows the `FormState` to recognize the updated items. Alternatively, use a `DropdownButton` and manually wrap it in a `FormField` so you can update the items like you want (if you even need the `FormField`).

Answer (score 0):

Update your Flutter version to 1.17.2, in which that bug is fixed.

Github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56898

Fixed in version 1.17.2: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#1172-may-28-2020